# Set selected items for DataGridView ComboBox failed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got confusion of setting / getting selected indexes of combobox fields inside.

```
    this.Parameter.DataSource = lambdacat.Dict();
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in LimView.Rows)
        {
            //( (ComboBox)row.Cells[1] ) ???
        }
    }
```

yes , this doesn't work :)

thank you

Comment: You can set the value by setting **Value** of the cell and retrieve the same by using **FormattedValue**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value == yourvalue;
```

and get the selected value as

```
(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).FormattedValue
```

To set a default selected value

```
(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value =(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[yourneededindex]
```

Comment: I've got a string array there , if yourvalue is a string it doesn't works :(

Comment: If you want to add the items of the array use **(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add(arrayval)** while looping the array

Comment: I presume you mean a default select, so you can use **(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value =(row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[yourneededindex]**